# Calculating number of Months from one date to another in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I was wondering if there is a way to calculate how many months it has been from one date to another in Power Bi.

For example the date would be October 1st 2014 and I would want to calculate how many months ago that was to the current date.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/datediff-function-dax

Comment: And [`TODAY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/today-function-dax) for current date.